# CSS Text color different between Firefox & Safari,

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari

I have a problem and I don't understand what exactly the problem is and how I can solve it.

I have a *Bootstrap Sidebar* with a menu title in a `<h5>` and some sub menus.

The `background-color` for titles is  `#454545` and the `text-color` should be `white`.

It works perfectly fine with **Firefox** but with **Safari** the `text-color` seems to be the same as the `background-color`. If I change text-color, only the glyphicon color changes.

#### HTML

```
<ul class="list">
  <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
    <h5><strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Actes Etat Civil</strong></h5>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="{%%20url">Fiches Identités</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="{%%20url">Actes de Naissance</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="{%%20url">Actes de Reconnaissance / Adoption</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="{%%20url">Actes de Mariage</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="{%%20url">Actes de Divorce</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="{%%20url">Actes de Décès</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
.list > h5 {
    color : white;
    padding: 2% 0% 2% 5%;
    background-color: #454545 !important;
    font-size: 25;
}
```

From Firefox :

[image]

From Safari :

[image]

Comment: `font-size: 25;`  is missing the pixel unit: `font-size: 25px;` not sure if that can be a reason for your problem, but you should still correct that.

Comment: I added `px` but nothing changed :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution based on `strong` parameter :

```
.list > h5 > strong {
        color : white;
        padding: 2% 0% 2% 5%;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .list > h5 {
        padding: 2% 0% 2% 5%;
        background-color: #454545 ;
    }
```

And it seems work with Safari and Firefox

Comment: hmm, that selector doesn't seem to match your HTML. The first one is saying "apply these styles to the strong tag whose parent is h5 whose parent class is _list_" ... that won't hit the target element. Perhaps you want a more general `.list h5`… which means "all h5's under parent with class _list_" ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me your selector is missing your target, as the `h5` is under the `li`.

So you'd need to do this to select the heading (I've added `> li` to the selector)

```
.list > li > h5 {
    color : white;
    padding: 2% 0% 2% 5%;
    background-color: #454545 !important;
    font-size: 25;
}
```

This seems to act the same in Firefox, Chrome and Safari for me.

The glyphicon may have its own rule elsewhere to give the proper color.

Comment: I applied your answer and I don't have `background-color` Then my title menu color is not white, but #454545

Comment: but do you have the _selector_ the same as I've posted? `.list > li > h5`